# Why do we need inheritance in JPA (ORM)?

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, jpa, orm, eclipselink

I have not yet used inheritance while using any ORM frameworks. I was trying to understand it through [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance) article but did not understand why and when exactly is inheritance needed/involved.

It is a bit tricky and seems unusual, since relational databases have no concept of inheritance.

What is the advantage of using inheritance in ORM? Are there any specific situations where it is mandatory?

<sub>Please give an example(s), if possible.</sub>

Comment: You use inheritance in your classes if you need it in your classes due to your object model. What you use in JPA depends on your classes, so if your classes have inheritance then you can do so in JPA. You don't "use inheritance in JPA" for any other reason than your object model has it

Answer (score 2):

For example, `PurchaseInvoice`, `SalesInvoice`, and others are subclasses of `Invoice`.  In `StockMovement`, you can have an attribute that refer to any `Invoice`.

```
public class StockMovement {

    @ManyToOne
    public Invoice invoice;

}
```

This is from OOP perspective.  You can retrieve common information shared in `Invoice` easily, for example:

```
for (StockMovement stockMovement: allResult) {
    stockMovement.invoice.number;
    stockMovement.invoice.date;
}
```

Inheritance is elegant but not necessary.  If you don't want to use inheritance or if you encounter some limitations in your JPA provider, you can just store the invoice's id in `StockMovement`.  For example:

```
@Entity
public class StockMovement {

     @Embedded public InvoiceId invoiceId;

}

@Embeddable
public class InvoiceId {

     public String invoiceId;

     public int invoiceType;
}
```

To retrieve the data, you must execute query manually:

```
for (StockMovement stockMovement: allResult) {
    if (stockMovement.invoice.invoiceType == 0) {
        execute query "FROM PurchaseInvoice p WHERE p.id = " + stockMovement.invoice.invoiceId);
    }
    if (stockMovement.invoice.invoiceType == 1) {
        execute query "FROM SalesInvoice p WHERE p.id = " + stockMovement.invoice.invoiceId);
    }
}
```

If you use inheritance, you can avoid such nasty `if`.

Comment: Do you know some links that demonstrate the purpose of inheritance with simple, easy-to-understand examples? I don't understand yet.

Answer (score 0):

**Why should ORMs have inheritance?**
Inheritance is an Object-Oriented Programming concept, and the objective of an ORM (Object-relational mapping) is to seamlessly link object-oriented Classes in your code to tables in the database. So it makes sense to include all OOP features including inheritance.

**What is a good example?**
Not the best example, but consider that you are making an application that stores information about various plants or animals. You want to classify them into a hierarchy: aquatic, aerial, mammals, birds etc. Inheritance will let you run queries like "select all mammals" or "select all birds" very easily.

Comment: Do you know some links that demonstrate the purpose of inheritance with simple, easy-to-understand examples? I don't understand yet.